# node-fetch HTTP Errors not being caught

Tags: javascript, node.js, exception, promise

I am having some problems with catching nodejs fetch exceptions
What I am expecting to happen  is:

- HTTP error of some sort occurs in my fetch call
- CheckResponseStatus function runs and an error an error is thrown with the server error status and text
- This error is caught and the ServerError function runs which (just for testing) will just print the error to the console.

However, the error printed to the console is:

```
Cannot connect to Server. Check you are using the correct IP Address and the server is running.
FetchError: request to http://localhost:3689/api/outputs failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3689
```

This is implying that the error I have thrown is not being caught, some default fetch error is being caught, and CheckResponseStatus is not being run.

My code is below

Node-Fetch HTTP Request:

```
async function getStatus(serverip,serverport){
  return await fetch(`http://${serverip}:${serverport}/api/outputs`)
  .then(this.checkResponseStatus)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .catch((err) => this.ServerError(err));
}
```

CheckResponseStatus Function:

```
checkResponseStatus(res) {
  if(res.ok){
      return res
  } 
  //will add elseif's here for different HTTP errors
  else {
      throw new Error(`The HTTP status of the response: ${res.status} (${res.statusText})`);
  }
}
```

ServerError Function:

```
ServerError(err){
  console.log('Cannot connect to Server. Check you are using the correct IP Address and the server is running.');
  console.log(err);
}
```

Thanks for any suggestions or help.

Comment: Is this `http://${serverip}:${serverport}/api/outputs` a `POST` endpoint?

Comment: This example is a `GET` However I am also using `POST` as well as `PUT` @zx01

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `fetch` is unable to connect to the remote server, it will `reject`. In your code, `checkResponseStatus` is never called because `fetch` is never able to get a response; the first two `.then` blocks are skipped because `fetch` rejected, so execution goes directly to the `.catch` block.

If you want network errors to run through `checkResponseStatus`, you can add a second `.catch` before the first `.then` and format the error into a "response":

```js
fetch(`http://${serverip}:${serverport}/api/outputs`)
  .catch(err => {
    // return a mock failed response for checkResponseStatus to handle
    return {
      ok: false,
      status: -1,
      statusText: 'Network Failure',
    };
  })
  .then(this.checkResponseStatus)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .catch((err) => this.ServerError(err));
```

However, I believe your code is currently running how I would expect it to - a network failure skips `checkResponseStatus`, which makes sense because there's no real response to check.

Comment: Ah I see that makes much more sense, thanks a lot.

Comment: One other thing, would it be possible to get the actual status code and status text from the http error? or is this not possible with this method? thanks @superhawk610

Comment: `fetch` errors (like most generic JS errors) don't provide a ton of useful debugging information. In the case of a network failure, `fetch` will reject with a `TypeError` that looks something like `{ message: 'Failed to fetch', stack: 'TypeError: Failed to fetch' }`. Since an HTTP connection is never established, no response is ever generated and there's not really a "status code" or "status text".

Comment: I see that makes sense, thanks for the reply and your solution works well as is. cheers